# Get outermost list from the current point

Tags: emacs, elisp, s-expression

From the point current position inside an Emacs buffer, how can I get the outermost list/s-expression which contains that point ?
Follows a few examples in order to illustrate what I want to achieve:

Example 1:

```
(defun xpto(arg)
  (+ 2 4)[point])
```

Output 1:

```
(defun xpto(arg)
      (+ 2 4))
```

Example 2:

```
(defun [point]xpto(arg)
  (+ 2 4))
```

Output 2:

```
(defun xpto(arg)
      (+ 2 4))
```

Example 3:

```
(defun xpto(arg)
  (+ 2 4))[point]
```

Output 3:

```
NIL
```

Is there any "off the shelf" function provided by Emacs that accomplishes the above mentioned behavior?
If not, can you guide me towards the easier approach in order to accomplish it ?

UPDATE #1

As suggested I tried the following approach:

```
;; Gets the outermost brackets based on point position
(defun get-outermost-brackets()
  (interactive)
  (car (last (nth 9 (syntax-ppss)))))


;; Assigns that function to a key
(global-set-key [(control p)] 'get-outermost-brackets)
```

However, after pressing CTRL+P I get no output no matter where the point is at.
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the function [`parse-partial-sexp`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Low_002dLevel-Parsing.html) which returns the [parser state](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Parser-State.html) (a 10-element list!) which you can use to figure out the start and end positions of your sexp.

Anther useful function will be [`scan-sexps`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Motion-via-Parsing.html).

UPDATE#1:

Your function `get-outermost-brackets` returns the position of of the outermost open paren, not a useful part of your buffer, and that value is not going to show in the echo area anyway.

UPDATE#2:

This will send the enclosing sexp to the echo area and the `*Messages*` buffer:

```
(defun get-enclosing-sexp (&optional pos)
  (interactive)
  (message "%s" (save-excursion
                  (goto-char (car (last (nth 9 (syntax-ppss)))))
                  (read (current-buffer)))))
```

Drop `message` if you want to return the sexp from the function instead of just showing it.

Where is my million?

Comment: I was expecting that position was printed in the minibuffer or in the *messages* buffer as an integer. So, the question for 1 million dollars: How can I get the s-expression starting at the position returned by get-outermost-brackets ?

Answer (score 4):

`(car (last (nth 9 (syntax-ppss))))` will give you the position of the outermost open paren (or nil if you're not within parentheses).  If you want to get the corresponding expression as an s-exp, you can go to that position and then use `read` to get it.

Comment: Ah, no I hadn't seen it.  As explained, the expression I provided only gives you the position of the outermost paren.  `car`, `last`, and `nth` just select the appropriate data from the output of `syntax-ppss`.  But if you want to get the corresponding sexp, you need to `goto-char` that position and `read`.